# Page is still appearing even though it doesn't exist anymore

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I encountered a problem with an app I was creating and it goes like this:

At login I had a sign-up button that directed to sign-up page. After deleting the button and commenting the sign-up page so it doesn't appear anymore, it still does appear and I don't know why, there's no trace to it anymore(routes, signup.js, auth.js, etc). What I don't understand is why the page still persists.

Comment: One of the possibilities : Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: , it's probably because it's stored in the web browser cache, so try to delete it

Comment: Another possibility is that you did not rebuild your code

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app`? Could be [service worker caching shenanigans](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2398).

Comment: I rebuilt the code, I cleared the npm cache but clearing the Browsers Cache did it. I feel dumb.. @WejdDAGHFOUS . Thanks all for your responses.

Comment: According the cache: Press CTRL + F5 to reload the page. It should download everything again.